# How to divide div into 3x3 equivalent divs?

Tags: css, web

Now i have a task to solve. I would like you to share with any way to divide 1 div into 3x3 DIVS only in percents and without bootstrap and flex model. Thanks

Comment: I made 9 divs on 1 and made them 33,333% width and height+display:inline-block + font-size: 0. And in order to Safari render in correctly i made the main div display: table. And because of that Firefox doesn't see in properly cuz i guess it has special relationships with tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works in all browsers:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}

.table{
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background:#eee;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.row{ display: table-row; }
.cell{ display: table-cell; }
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
    <div class="cell">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```